# I need to install a driver for broadcom BCM 43142 offline

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I've no internet connection except wifi and Ubuntu and no wifi adapter

```
broadcom bcm43142    pci id 17aa:0611  kernel alx
```

I can't add it without an internet connection.

I need a simple method please. Like double click and when I connect to internet It'll work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)